# Command Binding not working in pop-up window

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am using command binding which works in similar other windows but not one. I have checked for the *DataContext* and found it to be correct. event EventHandler `CanExecuteChanged` actually is never getting hit.
Codebehind is set as *DataContext* for XAML

**XAML**

```
<Button CommandParameter="Flow" Content="Test" 
        Command="{Binding SetAutoYAxisCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

**Code Behind**

```
public RelayCommand ExportHistoricalCommand { get; set; }
public RelayCommand1 SetAutoYAxisCommand { get; set; }

public TransientPipeDialog(TransientPipeModel transientPipeModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.ParentModel = transientPipeModel;
    this.TransientPipeModel = transientPipeModel.DeepCopy();
    ExportHistoricalCommand = new RelayCommand(ExportHistoricalData);
    SetAutoYAxisCommand = new RelayCommand1(SetAutoYAxis, o => true);
}
```

Comment: I assume your button is inside the <Popup></Popup>

Answer (score 0):

Try to Initialize your command when popup is opened:

```
private void Popup_Opened(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    SetAutoYAxisCommand = new RelayCommand1(SetAutoYAxis, o => true);
}   

<Popup Opened="Popup_Opened">
```